# Format for Borderlands 2 class tags

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

I am preemptively bringing up Borderlands 2 class tags as I expect more class specific questions to be asked in the coming days and weeks as people progress further in the game and unlock higher level abilities, and the number of Borderlands 2 questions to become large enough to warrant such tags.

The first question is whether we should use the character name (Salvador, Maya) or the class name (Gunzerker, Siren) as the suffix.  I think it's pretty obvious that the class name is correct choice for this.

The second question is what base to use for the tag.  25 characters is the maximum length of a tag, and [borderlands-2-gunzerker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-gunzerker) fits within that limit.  However, [borderlands-2-mechromancer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-mechromancer) doesn't.  While it isn't a problem right now, it will be down the road when this character is released.  The two options I propose are to cross that bridge when we come to it and use the [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2) base, or come up with a format now that will allow us to stay consistent when the Mechromancer is released.

Comment: Just for a sense of perspective, Diablo 3 has almost 2000 questions, with over 40 questions for each class tag.  I think we could hold off on creating class tags for borderlands-2 until its clear we're going to reach at least 50% of those numbers.

Comment: @bwarner: I wasn't suggesting that this should be done now, but rather that we be prepared for when it comes time to create these tags that they be created in a consistent manner.

Comment: Related: [Can we get tags for Borderlands 2 Classes?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6814/28182)

Answer (score 2):

I am not convinced the classes need their own tags. But assuming that they do, what's wrong with using the characters' names instead of classes? "Salvador" is just as long as "Gunzerker", and "Gaige" is far shorter than "Mechromancer".

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea. These proposed tags seem less informative, and more confusing to anyone who doesn't play the game (which is important for moderation). I can imagine someone asking "why does Borderlands 2 have tags for specific characters?" because it is not clear from looking that they are tag classes.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I would assume that the tag wiki and its excerpt would be able to clear that up...

Comment: I think keeping class names is still better than using character names.  Sometimes people rename the characters and then won't remember the original names.

Comment: BL does not allow for that. The characters' names are canonical, and you can only change a display name. :P

Comment: Still, I would very much like to avoid tags with names that are more obscure than necessary.