# Can we get tags for Borderlands 2 Classes?

Tags: support, tags, sub-tags

I have asked two class-specific Borderlands 2 questions, one about a particular skill in Axton's tree, and one skill in [Maya's tree](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102853/what-enemies-can-thoughtlock-turn-or-not-turn-into-allies). It could be useful for people looking for answers in class-specific categories.

I'm requesting to have separate tags for borderlands 2 classes, similar to how TF2 classes have their own tags (i.e. [tf2-spy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-spy), [tf2-soldier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-soldier), etc). I'm thinking [bl2-gunzerker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-gunzerker), [bl2-siren](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-siren), [bl2-assassin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-assassin), [bl2-mechromancer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-mechromancer), [bl2-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-commando) and so on.

Is this okay for me to add in?  Or are they best left the way they are, with no dedicated tags? And if yes, what's the best way to add the tag?  [bl2-axton](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-axton)? [borderlands2-axton](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands2-axton)? [bl2-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bl2-commando)? [borderlands2-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands2-commando)?

Comment: Related: [Format for Borderlands 2 class tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5364/28182)

Answer (score 10):

I do not think the scope offered by those tags is broad enough to necessitate their use. Similar to how there are not Mass Effect 3 class tags (despite their being 6 classes), the underlying gameplay between the characters (loot guns; shoot things) is identical, with the only difference being the active skill and the skill trees.

Compare this to Diablo 3 or Team Fortress 2, where gameplay varies entirely, dependent on which class you pick (limited weapon selection, every ability is class specific, etc).

Answer (score 7):

You don't need our approval to make tags. Go look through our [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2) questions and see how many Qs can be retagged. If there's enough, go ahead and retag — but if it's just 2 or so questions out of 390, *don't bother*.